# Should there be a space between quantitative units?

Tags: technical-writing, scientific-publishing

I understand that the SI standard for units is to have a space between the number and unit:

1. [Unit of measurement and formatting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/48026/unit-of-measurement-and-formatting/48027#48027)
2. https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html

But, does this apply to quantitative units? To abbreviate 1 Million, is it "1M" or "1 M"? "10k" or "10 k"?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely answered by your style guide. For example, in [Chicago Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Abbreviations/faq0094.html), there is no space (“usually”). In [AP](https://writingexplained.org/ap-style/ap-style-millions-billions-trillions), this type of abbreviation is only allowed in headlines for *M* and *B* and doesn’t have a space either.